# HTML / JS - Create new browsing session automatically when link clicked?

Tags: html, session, links

At the moment I am creating a web booking site using Google Calendar Appointment slots for my school (the school uses Google Apps).

Because the school wants users to use their Google Apps account when booking appointments, I have created a Google Site with an  gadget to place the booking page. To access the site you need to sign in with their school Google Apps email / password.

The issue is, if the student is already logged in with a personal Google / Gmail account, the booking page wants to book for the Gmail account, not the Google Apps account.

A way to get around this is to have the booking page open in a new browsing window. Is there a way to do this in HTML or JS with the link? (e.g. < a href="https://site.com" target="_**something**">My text here < /a >)??